# Trying to set the last modified time of a file in Java after renaming it

Tags: java, last-modified, file-rename

Here's the code I started off with:

```
long modifiedTime = [some time here];
File oldFile = new File("old_name.txt");
boolean renamed = oldFile.renameTo(new File("new_name.txt");
boolean timeChanged = oldFile.setLastModified(modifiedTime);

System.out.println("renamed: " + renamed);
System.out.println("time changed: " + timeChanged);
```

And the output I saw was:

```
renamed: true
time changed: false
```

---

But when I tried:

```
long modifiedTime = [some time here];
boolean renamed = new File("old_name.txt").renameTo(new File("new_name.txt"));
boolean timeChanged = new File("new_name.txt").setLastModified(modifiedTime);

System.out.println("renamed: " + renamed);
System.out.println("time changed: " + timeChanged);
```

It seemed to work fine, with this output:

```
renamed: true
time changed: true
```

---

Why is it that the second approach works, and the first one doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In first case you are trying to change the last modified attribute of file that no longer exists! Because you have just renamed it. In second case you are changing the attribute of existing valid file.

This happens because java class File is a thin wrapper over native commands. If you created instance `old = new File("oldname")`, then called `rename` and then invoked some method on `old` instance it actually performs system call and sends both the file name and the command. But the file name is irrelevant at this point.

I hope now it is clear.

Comment: Definitely clarifies it, thanks! However, it does seem like a bad API design then! I would assume that if I call renameTo on a file object, it'd be a mutating call that actually changes the filename of the file, but I guess it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`oldFile.renameTo(new File("new_name.txt"));` does not change where `oldFile` points. `oldFile`'s path is still `old_name.txt` after that call.

So the `setLastModified` call fails because `old_name.txt` no longer exists at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The `File` represents a path to a file or directory which may or may not exist.

When you rename a file, there is no long a file with the original name.